# Comparison Test prove $b_n \le a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

On my calculus II exam, my professor wanted us to determine whether the below series was convergent or divergent. $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n^3+1}}$$  I realized that it was most likely divergent, so I used the comparison test, trying to find a smaller series $b_n$ that was also divergent.  $$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n^3+1}}$$
$$b_n = \frac{1}{n^{\frac{4}{5}}}$$ He took off a bunch of points because he said $b_n$ was not $\le a_n$.

I would like to prove to him that $$b_n\le a_n$$ What would you recommend I do?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Is the exponent in $b_n$ really $4/5$?

Comment: Yes it was 4/5 @ Bernard. @lulu I was less sure about 3/4 for some reason

Comment: Well, $\frac 34$ is the way to go.  Sure $a_n<b_n$ with that choice, but the limit of their ratio is $1$.  Or you could work with $\frac 1{2n^{3/4}}$.

Comment: @lulu unfortunately I forgot how to perform the LCT during the exam

Comment: Do you know what equivalent functions are, in asymptotic calculus?

Comment: @bernard no, but happy to learn as long as it will convince him

Comment: I don't think you are convince your professor this way.  The inequality you want is true, at least for $n>1$, but it isn't obvious.  If you want to argue this way then proving that inequality is $100\%$ of the work, you can't just state it without proof.

Comment: @lulu my rational was that because 4/5 is a higher power than 3/4, putting it into the denominator will obviously decrease the value of the fraction. Regarding the +1, it will be insignificant as n approaches infinity.

Comment: Yes, but you have the additive factor of $1$ to cope with.  Easy if you work in the limit, but if you are doing that then it is easy to do the problem directly (see the posted solution from @Bernard for a clear solution along those lines).

Comment: Easiest way I can see to show what you want for large $n$ is to note that it is equivalent to $n^{16}>(n^3+1)^{5}$ which is clear for large $n$ since the right hand only has degree $15$.  In fact it is true for all $n≥2$ but I don't see a trivial way to show that (which does not mean there isn't one, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will speculate that your professor is penalizing you for being mathematically imprecise. (If I were your professor that's what I'd be inclined to do. Be glad I'm not your professor.) That is, in comparing $\sum a_n$ to $\sum b_n$, you are tacitly saying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ because $a_n\ge b_n$ **for all $n$**. But that is not true.  In particular $a_1=1/\sqrt[4]2$ is *less* than $b_1=1$.

There is, of course, an easy fix: Just say that $\sum a_n$ diverges because $\sum b_n$ diverges and $a_n\ge b_n$ for all $n$ **greater than or equal to $2$**.  I'm not sure that that would completely mollify your professor, but at least it would be an indication that you've given some thought to why the inequality is true.

Proving the inequality is true for $n\ge2$ is actually a little delicate, since $1/2^{4/5}\approx0.574$ is awfully close to $1/\sqrt[4]{2^3+1}=1/\sqrt3\approx0.577$.  One proof begins something like this:

$${1\over n^{4/5}}\le{1\over\sqrt[4]{n^3+1}}\iff(n^3+1)^5\le n^{16}\iff\cdots$$

At this point I would be tempted to abandon the attempt to prove the inequality all the way down to $n=2$ and instead say

$$n\ge32\implies n^{16}\ge32n^{15}=(n^3+n^3)^5\ge(n^3+1)^5\implies{1\over\sqrt[4]{n^3+1}}\ge{1\over n^{4/5}}$$

and conclude that $\sum a_n$ diverges because $\sum b_n$ diverges and $a_n\ge b_n$ for all $n\ge32$.

But what I really suggest is instead to compare $a_n=1/\sqrt[4]{n^3+1}$ to $b_n={1\over2n}$. The proof of the relevant inequality is straightforward:

$${1\over2n}\le{1\over\sqrt[4]{n^3+1}}\iff n^3+1\le16n^4\iff1\le(16n-1)n^3$$

and the rightmost inequality is obviously true for $n\ge1$.

Comment: For the comparison rest it suffices that $\{n\in \Bbb N: a_n>b_n\}$ is finite, i.e. bounded. However if the proposer wrote on the test that $b_n\le a_n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ then a deduction of marks is justifiable....To the proposer: For all $n \in \Bbb N$ we have $a_n\ge (n^3+n^3)^{-1/4}=2^{-1/4}n^{-3/4}\ge 2^{-1/4}n^{-1}.$

Answer (score 0):

You’re right. Observe:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n} = \ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{-1/20} = 0$

Which implies that$b_n$ becomes asymptotically slower than $a_n$.

Comment: I am not debating you, but the graph of both functions suggests to me that b_n is smaller over the interval [1,infinity) https://photos.app.goo.gl/1EvrwagieYGUBNoL9 Does your solution take the interval into account? @gdepaul

Comment: The ratio $b_n/a_n$ is asymptotically $n^{-1/20}$, not $n^{1/20}$.

Comment: Lol, my bad . I made a calc error on my end. @ZekeLegge you are right, but i think your professor actually wanted you to perform the calculation on n^{-3/4} instead of n^{-4/5}

Answer (score 0):

So here a very fast way to go, with *equivalents*. Remember two functions are *asymptotically equivalent* if their ratio tends to $1$ at $\infty$.

For instance, a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term. The  main rule to know is that equivalence is compatible with multiplication and division, but *not* with addition nor subtraction. Also, a function which has a finite limit $\ell$ at $\infty$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\ell$, and conversely.

The theorem we use is that two series with *positive* asymptotically equivalent terms both converge or both diverge.

In the case at hand, we have $\;n^3+1\sim_\infty n^3$, hence $\;\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n^3+1}}\sim_\infty \dfrac 1{n^{3/4}}$, and the latter diverges.

Comment: Very interesting. It all hinges on dismissing the additive 1 because it is an infinite series, which is intuitive enough.

Comment: Even a term in, say, $n^2$ could be dismissed.